# Why is OSX continually asking for firewall permission for my app which is signed?

Tags: xcode, macos, firewall, osx-elcapitan

OSX El Capitan version 10.11.4

I am building an application in Xcode and signing it with an official developer cert. I then package this into a DMG which I am also signing.

My application listens for TCP connections on a specific port (7772 in this case).

I verified the signature:

```
$ codesign -dvvvv /Applications/Foo.app/

Executable=/Applications/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo
Identifier=com.foo.bar.Foo
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=69949 flags=0x0(none) hashes=2179+4 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=188672458e5a40f9f5eb72a864ecaee6dbb46970
CandidateCDHash sha256=c0f4bc81011db7123d8bf881d14868e6e4203cdf
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CDHash=c0f4bc81011db7123d8bf881d14868e6e4203cdf
Signature size=8912
Authority=Developer ID Application: *** Inc. (3********2)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=Apr 15, 2016, 4:12:19 PM
Info.plist entries=27
TeamIdentifier=3*********2
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=32
Internal requirements count=1 size=192
```

When I reboot with the firewall enabled I get a prompt asking me to allow the application to accept incoming connections.

If I say ok, then it works (obviously) and if "deny" then the firewall blocks the port.

My question is **why am I getting prompted if my app signature is good**?

Once I hit "accept" I don't see it in my firewall applications either.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my firewall is configured to **"Automatically allow signed software to receive incoming connections"**. That's why I'm puzzled since my app is being signed and passes codesign verification.

Answer (score 1):

According to this:[https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aZjW.png)

you should check the Code Designated Requirement:
codesign -vv yourapp.app